# Who knows about the format of fdb_latexmk?

Tags: latexmk

The build tool `latexmk` is widely used.
When compiling `xxx.tex` with `latexmk xxx`,
an intermediate file `xxx.fdb_latexmk` is created.
Although I can figure out some properties of that text file,
I want to know for sure.
I researched in the source code of `latexmk`
which is available at https://github.com/debian-tex/latexmk/blob/master/latexmk.pl,
but my perl knowledge is so weak, that I ... well, I don't really understand.

What I understand already:

- first line is `# Fdb version 4` could refer to latexmk version which is 4.xxx in my case.
- the rest is are sections as described below. There are cases with a single section.

Each section has a certain form:

- first line is the only line without indent.
  Could be something like

```
["lualatex"] 1702989679 "bewerbung.tex" "bewerbung.pdf" "bewerbung" 1702989681 0
```

Seems to refer to a rule and so I call it a rule line.

- each subsequent lines following until line `(generated)` refer to a source,
  thus i call it a source line.
- then comes a line `(generated)`,
- each line following `(generated)` until line `(rewritten before read)`
  seems to refer to a target, so I call it a target line.
- the last line of a section is `(rewritten before read)`

Questions:

- Is the above list a general form or is this true for my files only accidentally?
- The rule line seems to start with ["rule name"]
  where the rule name can be user defined or builtin.
  The rest of the line, in particular the many numbers are not clear to me.
- The source lines seem to start with `"file path"` referring to a source file.
  Then comes a number I cannot interpret, then the size of the file and a hash, most probably to identify changes, then something in quotes: is empty if the source file is not created but else the name of the rule created the file.
- The target lines seem clear: name of generated file in quotes.

Who can help me to find out the details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latexmk maintainer here.  Since .fdb_latexmk files are intended for latexmk's internal use, there is (currently) no official documentation.   This answer is the closest approach to documentation.

In the latexmk source code, the fairly short subroutine rdb_write effectively defines the format, by showing what is written.  The names of the variables whose values are written give an indication of the meaning.

The version in the first line is simply a version number for the layout used for the .fdb_latexmk files.  Whenever I find I need to change the kinds of information in these files, I update the version number.  When latexmk reads an .fdb_latexmk file, it checks the fdb version number, and abandons reading if the version number is different than the current one.  (The file would evidently have been created by a different version of latexmk.)  The current fdb version is 4.

The indentation is purely a convenience for humans reading the file, and is ignored when the file is read by latexmk.  Blank lines and comment lines are ignored (except for the initial comment line giving the fdb version number). Comment lines are those beginning with possible white space followed by '#' or '%'.

The overall structure is exactly what you see.

For each rule there is a section that is introduced by a line that starts ["..."] with the name of the rule. The fields that follow on the same line are:

1. System time at the start of the last time the rule was run.
2. Primary source file, e.g., the document's .tex file for pdflatex.
3. Primary destination file (if any), e.g., the output .pdf file for pdflatex.
4. The base name for files, e.g., log files and the like.
5. The system time when the rule was last checked as to whether a rerun was needed.
6. A status code for the last run: 0 for success.  Currently, other possible values are: 1 if the rule failed to create the intended output file, 2 if there was some other kind of error.

Following that rule line is a line for each of the (known) source files of the rule:  Each line has the name of the file (in double quotes), then the modification time, size and md5 signature of the file, as measured just before the rule was run.  Finally there is the name of the rule, if any, that generated the file, in double quotes.

After that there is another part of the rule data headed by a line containing '(generated)'.  This is a list of filenames (in double quotes, one per line) for files generated during the running of the rule.

The final part of the rule data is headed by a line containing '(rewritten before read)'.  It is followed by a list of filenames (again in double quotes, one per line).  Commonly this list is empty. Any files here existed at the beginning of the run, and were read during the run, but they got rewritten before the first time that they were read.

I should add that when non-ASCII filenames are encountered, they are coded as UTF-8.

Comment: Wow, thank you.. the only thing I did not understand is the section (rewritten before read): these files were read by latexmk, i.e. latexmk detected their presence, but some other tool changed before latexmk could really grasp the content?

Comment: What happens is that during a single run of *latex, some packages write a file at some point, and read it back later in the same run.  The symptom is in the .fls file where the first mention of a file is in an OUTPUT line, and then there is later an INPUT line for the same file. (Right now I don't remember which packages.)